# Can I know how to deploy my spring boot application on a centos server......To mention this application worked fine on the localhost

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, centos, production

I have developed a spring boot application using spring sts IDE and works fine on the embedded tomcat server. Now, I have a remote server with root access running centos. Now I need to deploy my spring boot application in the production mode... I am really confused how to proceed further. Can anyone give me a clear idea and instructions to do so.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

1. First of all, your remote server must have java installed. (connect with putty)
   e.g. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-centos-and-fedora
2. If you're running spring boot, you probably use embedded tomcat. So, build jar package with you IDE, or just open your project folder in console and type `mvn install`. Jar with your application will be created in *Target* folder. e.g. myapp-version.jar
3. Now copy this jar to remote server. You can do it with ftp connection, with programs like filezilla. When you connect to remote, you will see folder structure, and you can drag and drop files from your computer to remote with no problem.
4. Now connect to your remote with putty, go to folder where you copied jar and run it. Like this: `java -jar myapp-version.jar`.

And that's it. If your app starts on 8080 with no context-path, then http://remoteServerAddress:8080/
In production you should of course map this url to some domain name, context path or whatever, so that the user can not see the port numbers etc. But I don't know how far this question goes.